# XNA Home Screen

Tags: xna

In my XNA project I have a Game class but I wish to add a Menu screen which will be shown upon application launch. Does anyone know how I can add this? I can't seem to find anything in the project which will do this...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing comes with XNA by default for game screens.

However, there is an official [XNA sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) which covers this topic and has useful code to tackle multiple game screens.

Comment: Right, I see.... I wonder why Microsoft didn't add anything built-in and straight forward to all of this.. Thank you Scott.