# XNA - How to show different screens?

Tags: windows, xna, screen, xna-4.0

I am a newbie in XNA. I am creating a game which have 2 screens(main screen, playgame screen) what I want to do is that when on mainscreen user presses number "1" the screen switches to a new screen where the user starts to play the game. I am not able to figure out any class in XNA which will help me in switching screens. Please tell me how to do it.

**Any help would be hightly appreciated!**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15714661/155407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNa does not really have a concept of "screens" it is something for the developer to define. You say you have two screens already, are these separate C# files with their own Update and Draw functions?

If so, start by calling those functions for the main screen from the Game class. When the user presses a button, switch to calling the functions on the PlayGame screen. There may be other functions you need to call but that is the general principle if this is the way you currently have your scenes defined.

Comment: That's OK, first explain what you mean by you have two screens. Do you have those two screens created already or are you asking about how you would initially create them?

Comment: How I would create them..!